# Why this question is rant and not a real question?

Tags: discussion

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/who-are-these-hypocrytes-aroud-prophet-in-medina-that-quran-talks-about-them

this question is based on a verse of Quran. the verse is clearly talking about hypocrites around prophet in medina. it is not my fault for seeimg rant. this is language of Quran.

this question is only asking for tafseer of this verse and knowing the persons this verse is talking about them.

why we should not know the persons Quran is talking about them?

Answer (score 1):

> this question is only asking for tafseer of this verse and knowing the persons this verse is talking about them.

If the question was *only* asking for tafsir of this verse, as you claim, then the majority of the text you posted is irrelevant.  Your "question" in that case was no more than a one-liner, followed by two paragraphs of "fabricated hadith" this and "fake Islam" that.

And as it stands, the post looks like little more than an excuse to stir up yet more Shia-Sunni discord under the guise of a token question, which is not by any means constructive.  Whether or not such was your intent is irrelevant; the question as phrased is not suitable for this site.

Stack Exchange is a site dedicated to building a database of high-quality questions and answers.  We expect questions to be focused and answerable.  Quoting directly from [the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> You should only ask *practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*

One of the criteria for a constructive question is that it does not ramble off into irrelevant rants, especially irrelevant rants that may stir up fourteen hundred plus years of political turmoil.

Comment: this question is a very high quality question. there are many tafseer having conflict in shia sunni. the intent is not shia sunni discord. this is your interpret. knowing the hypocrites around prophet is very practical and constructive and has many benefits specially in hadith. what you call rant are facts derived from this verse. Quran says there are hypocrites around prophet and this means "fake Islam" and "fabricated hadith" are possibly made by those hypocrites. all are derived from verse and what I said is for showing importance of this tafseer.they are not rant. but logical possibility.

Comment: please define rant clearly. I do not underestand how this question is rant. prophet said there will be 72 sects in Muslims. this question only talks about logical possibility of a fake Islam made by hypocrite sahaba. it is not directed to any special sect to be rant.

Comment: @Ahmadi - It is a rant because it is a [leading question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question). Basically you're asking a question, then *suggesting* the answer.

Comment: @SystemDown you have 2 claim that can be accuse (Tuhmat). if they are true may Allah help me correct myself and if false may Allah forgive you. leading question is a question that suggests answer. question is about who are them? how this question suggests the answer?! I really do not know them. I only guess. 2- even if we assume it is a leading question. why a leading question is rant? I think one of us have misunderstanding in definition of rant. let me know where is leading to answer to I edit.

Comment: my actual problem is that I want to know all of the hypocrites around prophet that Quran and hadith is talking about them to filter hadithes narrated by them. how should I ask this to not be closed?

Comment: @SystemDown please reply where is the suggested answer or reopen it. it not fair to not reply me.